# In excel, how do I return column 2, by searching for the values in column 1 in another cell?

Tags: excel, lookup

### ***Table 1***

```
ColA.....ColB

Little boy    blue
The red car   White men can't jump
```

***Table 2***

```
ColA.......ColB

Red.......Reddish

White....A very light shade

Blue......A color typically reserved for boys
```

I am trying to fill in ColA of Table 1.

I want ColA, of table 1, to contain a single value from Table 2, ColB.  Based on ColA of Table 2, being found in ColB of table 1

What function would I put in table 1, col1 ?
In other words, cell A2 would contain "Reddish", of table 1

Comment: What about below answer? Solved your problem or not?

Answer (score 0):

Assume table 2 is in cells `A6:B8`. Colours is a named range `$A6:$A8`.

```
=INDEX($B$6:$B$8,SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(colours,B1))*ROW($1:$3)))
```